# Get JSON Data in Servlet with POST Method from Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, java

I tried to get the JSON Data , which I send from Javascript to my Java POST Method. The problem is, that the data in the Servlet is always NULL.

But if write the data as:

> data: {Aktion: '2'}

I got the parameter in my Servlet. Just the JSON Array dosen't work for me.

Here's my JS code:

```
var jsonDate = {
    Aktion : 2,
    Emplid_MA: 11151154,
    Userid_Meister : "acstoll",
    Beurteilungsdatum: 2019-12-09,
    Kriterium_1 : 1,
    Kriterium_2 : 3,
    Kriterium_3 : 1,
    Kriterium_5 : 4,
    Kriterium_6 : 3,
    Kriterium_7: 2,
    Einsatz_mehrere_Stationen : 1,
    ausgefuehrte_Taetigkeiten : 1,
    Weiterbeschaeftigung: 2,
    Weiterbeschaeftigung_Verbesserung : "test"
}

var json = JSON.stringify(jsonDate);

$.ajax({
    url : urlANUe + "Mitarbeiter_Einzel_Update",
    dataType : "json",
    method : "POST",
    contentType : "application/json",
    headers : {
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    },
    data: {jsonDaten:json},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("alle MA");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr, status, text) {
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

And here's my Servlet:

```
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    Connection con = null;

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");

 //This is always NULL
    String jsonStr = request.getParameter("jsonDaten");


    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    String ak = jsonObj.getString("Aktion");


    String Aktion = request.getParameter("Aktion");
[...]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that i had to remove the contentTyp in my JS file.
No it works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing "data: {jsonDaten:json}". What is jsonDaten? Just pass the stringifed JSON variable "json" properly. Like this:

**
var json = JSON.stringify(jsonDate);

```
headers : {
        "Accept" : "application/json"
    },
    data: json,
```

**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting resuest parameters instead of loading the payload, and parsing is as JSON.

Try something like this:

```
JsonReader json = Json.createReader(request.getInputStream);
JsonObject jsonObj = json.readObject();
```

### Edit

You did not specified which JSON implementation you are using, so I used the one built in to the JavaEE...